# How to do multi-table joins in MySQL involving composite foreign keys?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

Sample tables are as follows:

```
SCENARIO_NATIONS
[scenID]  [side]  [nation]

scen001     1     Germany
scen001     2     Britain
scen001     2     Canada

SCENARIO_NEEDUNITS
[scenID]  [unitID]

scen001    0001
scen001    0003
scen001    0107
scen001    0258
scen001    0759

UNIT_BASIC_DATA
[unitID]  [nation]  [name]

  0001    Germany   Mortars
  0003    Germany   Infantry
  0107    Britain   Lt
  0258    Britain   Infantry
  0759    Canada    Kilted Yaksmen
```

**Goal:** given a `scenID`, pull a list of units from the database sorted by `side, nation, name`.

I can do everything except for the `side` inclusion with:

```
SELECT scenario_needunits.scenID, unit_basic_data.nation, unit_basic_data.name
FROM scenario_needunits
LEFT OUTER JOIN unit_basic_data
ON scenario_needunits.unitID=unit_basic_data.unitID
WHERE scenario_needunits.scenID='scen001'
ORDER BY unit_basic_data.nation ASC, unit_basic_data.name ASC
```

I've tried just dropping the `SCENARIO_NATIONS` table in as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on `scenID` but what ends up happening is that **ALL** units come back with a `side` of `1` because that's always the first side listed for the `scenID` in the `SCENARIO_NATIONS` table.

Conceptually, what I think needs to happen is `SCENARIO_NATIONS` must be joined to both the `scenID` (to restrict it to just that scenario) and to each unit's `nation` but I don't have any idea how to do that.

---

OMG Ponies' code results in each unit being listed twice, once per side, rather than only for the side which its parent nation is on:

```
[scenID]  [side]   [nation]   [name]
BaBu001     1   America   CAPT
BaBu001     1   America   HMG
BaBu001     1   Germany   CAPT
BaBu001     1   Germany   GREN
BaBu001     2   America   CAPT
BaBu001     2   America   HMG
BaBu001     2   Germany   CAPT
BaBu001     2   Germany   GREN
```

correct results would be

```
[scenID]  [side]   [nation]   [name]
BaBu001     1   America   CAPT
BaBu001     1   America   HMG
BaBu001     2   Germany   CAPT
BaBu001     2   Germany   GREN
```

---

And to get that we modify the code like so:

```
SELECT sn.side, snu.scenid, ubd.nation, ubd.unitname
FROM sn
JOIN snu 
        ON snu.scenid=sn.scenid AND snu.scenid = 'scenID'
JOIN ubd
        ON ubd.nation=sn.nation AND ubd.unitid=snu.unitid //double join is the key change
ORDER BY sn.side, ubd.nation, ubd.unitname
```

Comment: Let me add that I really don't know much at all about joins, so there's a reasonable possibility that my approach is fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want `UNIT_BASIC_DATA` rows/records with a relationship in the `SCENARIO_NEEDUNITS` table, use:

```
  SELECT snu.scenid,
         sn.side,
         ubd.nation,
         ubd.name
    FROM UNIT_BASIC_DATA ubd
    JOIN SCENARIO_NEEDUNITS snu ON snu.unitid = ubd.unitid
                               AND snu.scenid = ?
    JOIN SCENARIO_NATIONS sn ON sn.scenid = snu.scenid
ORDER BY snu.scenid, sn.side, ubd.nation, ubd.name
```

Replace the `?` with whatever `scenid` you wish to look for.

You don't need to specify `ASC` - it's the default.

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up the basic query, but my problem is that I also want the side for each unit, and to sort by side first. Each scenario has 2 sides, and I want to the results order to be Side 1 > Nations > Units then Side 2 > Nations > Units as opposed to the current situation which is just Nations > Units

Comment: @Andrew Heath: Updated answer.  Providing an example of your desired output would help in the future, for when my reading comprehension fails.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts but still not quite right, please see my updated post with results of your query vs desired results.

Comment: Hey hey! Figured it out by messing with your example a bit, posted the modified query above! Thank you!!!